# How can I get self. variable from a parent class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, oop

This might be very bad example, but I'm new with OOP, I'm trying to get the same `self.number list` that I have created inside `random_number` without calling `random.randint` again. but `self.number` is empty when I'm calling inside `class B`, what can be the right approach?

```
import random
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = []

    def random_number(self):
        for i in range(4):
            self.number.append(random.randint(1, 100))
            random.randint(1, 100)

        print("from class A", self.number)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # something here

    def get_name(self):
        A().random_number()
        print("from class B", self.number)

B().get_name()
```

Comment: It's not related to the problem, but why do you have a line with just `random.randint(1, 100)`?

Comment: What do you mean calling it *again*? I only see a single call to `.random_number()`

Comment: Just change `A().random_number()` to `self.random_number()`.  Issue is A().random_number() is calling random_number for a new object.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you're trying to do, but it seems like you might want `number` to be a class property rather than an instance property.

Comment: There's a helpful tutorial on inheritance here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp

Answer (score 3):

Doing `A().random_number()` will create a new instance of class `A` then call the `random_number` method of that newly created instance, and that's obviously not what you want.

You need to access the method from the instance of class `B`, and since you are extending the class `A` to create class `B`, you can use the parent class methods directly into the child class i.e. `self.random_number`:

```py
import random
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = []

    def random_number(self):
        for i in range(4):
            self.number.append(random.randint(1, 100))
            random.randint(1, 100)

        print("from class A", self.number)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # something here

    def get_name(self):
        # A().random_number()
        self.random_number()   #<--- calling self.random_number()
        print("from class B", self.number)

B().get_name()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
from class A [16, 24, 100, 47]
from class B [16, 24, 100, 47]
```

Comment: You don't need to use `super()` when calling the `random_number()` method. Methods are inherited.

Comment: Yes, I was just modifying the answer

Comment: You would never call `super().random_number()` unless there were a shadowing method in the current class and you need to bypass it. Mentioning it here just adds confusion.

Comment: That is also `True`, I just removed the entire part containing `super`

Comment: "of the newly created class" -> "of the newly created *instance*"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, that was a typo, thanks for pointing!